# Additional rolls to see all faces of a die

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

> Suppose that a fair die is rolled repeatedly; different rolls are
>   independent.
>   ***N*** is the minimum number of rolls till each of the six faces of the die shows up at least once.
>
> Suppose that i distinct faces have already shown up, i = 1; 2; 3; 4;
>   5. N_i is the minimum number of additional rolls after i distinct faces have shown up till another distinct face (one of the remaining 6
>   - i faces) shows up. Derive the pmf.

I know that **N** is Geometrically distributed by 1/6, however, I am having trouble figuring out if **N_i** is geometrically distributed like **N**, and why is that different if not? How would the p.m.f of **N_i** be derived?

Comment: 1. The answer to your question is apparent in the answer to the linked question. 2. No, your N is not geometrically distributed.

Comment: @Did: I cannot find the question referred to.

Comment: Quote: "After that, the random time until a third (different) result appears is geometrically distributed with parameter of success 4/6, hence with mean 6/4" Surely you can generalize this, no?

Comment: @Did Thanks! I saw this page, but couldn't see the link to my question before. However, I think sourav's answer is closer to the answer to my question.